# SAML2 Bearer Assertion profile for OAuth in WSO2 IS 4.5.0 failing

Tags: oauth-2.0, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

We are using WSO2 IS 4.5.0 for our product implementation.  We are implementing SAML2 based SSO between our product applications.  And our REST APIs are secured using OAuth2.  Now, we are trying to configure IS to issue SAML2 bearer token for OAuth applications.

These are the steps that we followed

1. Added a tenant 'sample.com'
2. Added SAML SSO service provider (travelocity.com) within tenant 'sample.com'
3. Added OAuth application within tenant 'travelocity'
4. Added Trusted Identity Provider as defined in [SAML2 Bearer Assertion Profile for OAuth 2](http://docs.wso2.org/display/IS450/SAML2+Bearer+Assertion+Profile+for+OAuth+2.0)
5. Added wso2carbon.jks public certificate to Trusted Identity Provider [This is the same certificate used during SAML Authentication Request generation]

And when I try to invoke OAuth2Service.issueAccess, I get the following error

```
Signature was either invalid or signing key could not be established as trusted
```

Any help to resolve will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone from WSO2 help me please!

Answer (score 0):

We have missed configuring public certificate of the tenant 'sample.com' in trusted identity provider configuration, that resolves the issue!